# Is it grammatically possible to use prepositions 'of/from' in the following sentence: 'I'm a long way off (of/from) being fluent.'?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, direct-objects, indirect-objects

I am not sure whether I can use prepositions 'of/from' in this kind of structures and how am I to know how to use them properly? I have looked the phrase up and the only examples they give are when it comes without an object as in: September was a long way off. Success is still a long way off. Holiday is a long way off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collocation is **a long way (off) from [something]**

The [something] can be expressed by a gerund-participial clause [I think that's the contemporary label]:

... a long way off from **being fluent** ...

or a noun-phrase:

... a long way off from **fluency**

**off** is optional.

It is faintly figurative, a distance metaphor.

Comment: The thing is that in the textbook it was 'I'm a long way off being fluent ' without any preposition; so I guess 'from' could be omitted or is it a typo?

Comment: **I'm a long way off being fluent**  is certainly something that could come out of the mouth of a native speaker. It is colloquial. The following is not an impossible conversation: *How's your motorcycle, Bobby? I heard you crashed it into a window down at the hardware store when you was drunk two weekends ago.  --  I got it in the shop, but it's a long way off being fixed. I'm still waiting for parts.*